# Extract data from a map (JsonObj)

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape all of the French map.

I've got one issue :

1 - I'm limited by the zoom of the map

```
import requests




url ='https://www.iadfrance.fr/agent-search-location?southwestlat=47.0270782&southwestlng=-2.1560669&northeastlat=47.4930807&northeastlng=-1.0093689'
jsonObj = requests.get(url).json()
emails = jsonObj['agents']
#print (emails)


for agent in emails: 
    email = agent['email']
    print(email)
```

Thank you

Comment: What is your problem? this codes runs well

Comment: Yes, this code is not the problem.
If you look the website, I can fetch a limited zone of email.
This is limited by the zoomOut of the map api.
I would like to fetch all of the agent from France not only a department.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to utilize the longitude, latitude parameters in the request to "zoom out"

You can either change them manually, or I'm a fan of [osmnx](https://geoffboeing.com/2016/11/osmnx-python-street-networks/). You can use that to get the boundaries of different areas, then set a radius in meters to create your boundary box:

```
import requests
import osmnx as ox
import os

os.environ["PROJ_LIB"] = "C:/Users/xxxxxxx/AppData/Local/Continuum/anaconda3/Library/share"; #fixr

# Get a boundary box of a city/place/address
city = ox.gdf_from_place('Paris, France')

# Distance to make boundary from center in meters
# Essentially allows you to zoom out
distance = 300000

# Get centroid of that city/place boundary box
point = ( city['geometry'].centroid.x.iloc[0], city['geometry'].centroid.y.iloc[0] )

# Get a new boundary box a certain distance in North, South, East, West directions for x meters
boundary = ox.bbox_from_point(point, distance=distance , project_utm=False, return_crs=False)

sw_lat = boundary[3]
sw_lng = boundary[0]*-1
ne_lat = boundary[2]
ne_lng = boundary[1]*-1

# website to scrape https://www.iadfrance.fr/trouver-un-conseiller

url ='https://www.iadfrance.fr/agent-search-location'

# Here is the coordinates from orginial post
#payload = {
#'southwestlat': '47.0270782',
#'southwestlng': '-2.1560669',
#'northeastlat': '47.4930807',
#'northeastlng': '-1.0093689'}


payload = {
'southwestlat': sw_lat,
'southwestlng': sw_lng,
'northeastlat': ne_lat,
'northeastlng': ne_lng}


jsonObj = requests.get(url, params=payload).json()
emails = jsonObj['agents']
#print (emails)


for agent in emails: 
    email = agent['email']
    print(email)
```

Answer (score 1):

I find the right way, I must think out the box.
I've set 2 geographic data manually in a very very large area. ( one in Atlantic and an other in Russia ).
It works !

```
import requests


url ='https://www.iadfrance.fr/agent-search-location?southwestlat=9.884462&southwestlng=-35.58398&northeastlat=68.714264&northeastlng=44.796407'
jsonObj = requests.get(url).json()
emails = jsonObj['agents']
#print (emails)


for agent in emails: 
    email = agent['email']
    print(email)
```